# Parse yaml config map data from k8s

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes, yaml

I'm using the following code to get k8s config map data.

This code is working however I’m not sure regarding the unmarshal, is it a bit verbose, is there a robust way to achieve this?

```
cm, e := c.Kubernetes.CoreV1().ConfigMaps(“ns1”).Get(“vs-manifest”, metav1.GetOptions{})
if e != nil {
    return errors.New(“error “occurred”)

}

//here I want to get the data
var cmData map[string]string
e = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(cm.Data["cm1.yaml"]), &cmData)
if err != nil{
  return errors.New(“error “occurred”)
}

//here i need to read rzr field
appVersion := strings.ReplaceAll(cmData[“rzr”], ".", "-")
```

This is the config map `vs-manifest`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vs-manifest
  namespace: ns1
data:
  cm1.yaml: |
    version: 1.5
    repo: milestones
    rzr: 1.0005.044
```

Comment: "cleaner" is always an opinion, which makes for bad questions. Can you maybe narrow your requirements down a bit? What exactly is the offending part of this code?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - I think about more robust code as I need to run it in prod, I got an answer which Im checking right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some modification suggestions:

```golang
// Once you have the configMap, check whether cm1.yaml file exist or not?

var cmFile string 
if value, ok:= cm.Data["cm1.yaml"]; ok {
  cmFile = value
}

// while unmarshal-ing yaml files, use map[string]interface
// otherwise error may occur.
// Case:
//| a:
//|   b: value
//|   c: 
//|     d: value2

cmData := make(map[string]interface{})
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(cmFile), cmData)
if err != nil {
  return errors.New("error occurred")
}

var apiVersion string
// Check whether the "rzr" exist or not
if value, ok := cmData["rzr"]; ok {
  // convert the value from interface to string
  // using type assertion.
  stringValue, valid := value.(string)
  // if successfully converted to string
  if valid {
    apiVersion = strings.ReplaceAll(stringValue, ".", "-")
  } else {
    return errors.New("failed to convert")
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!, you said " otherwise error may occur` which kind of error do you mean?

Comment: @PeterSO Added a sample case. `map[string]string` will fail in nested yaml files.

Comment: im trying it now, when I try to do `appVersion := strings.ReplaceAll(cmData[“rzr”], ".", "-")` I got error, any idea?

Comment: the error is: `Cannot use 'cmData["rzr"]' (type interface{}) as type string`

Comment: @PeterSO which `apiVersion` you're trying to get? Do your configMap has a key `rzr` in the data field? Add the yaml of the configMap to the question body.

Comment: could you please advice ?